# Extracting substring with awk if the string includes regular expressions

Tags: bash, awk

I have many strings like this

```
i=./M1/CustomersList/HTP/Boston/FCT/output_GetCaseList_abs.txt
```

I need to extract the M1 code and the FCT but I am unable to do so, likely due to the regular expressions. FCT I can do with `echo ${i:30:3}`, but for M1 nothing seems to work - my last try was `grep -oP '.*\K(?<=.\/)\w+(?=\/Cus)' $i ;`

The length of the string can vary (but it always starts with /F) and /M1/ is always in the same position

Hope somebody can help. Thanks!

Comment: You say the section you want to find `always starts with /F` but you don't say that no other section can also start with `/F`, e.g. if your input was about a customer in `Flagstaff` instead of `Boston`. You imply that `FCT` can appear in different positions but maybe not. 1 sample input line isn't enough for us to guess the general form of your input and test a potential solution. Please provide about 4 or 5 **diverse** input lines and the expected output given that input so we can help you solve your real problem as opposed to just producing the expected output for that 1 line of sample input

Answer (score 3):

You could try following `awk` programs.

To get `FCT` likewise strings try: Since position of string is NOT fixed as well as only `/F` is fixed, so I am trying to match `/F` till next occurrence of `/` so it will catch any value after `/F` but before next occurrence of `/` here.

```
echo "$i" | awk 'match($0,/\/F[^/]*/){print substr($0,RSTART+1,RLENGTH-1)}'
```

To get `M1` try following `awk` program, since position of `M1` is always fixed(as per OP in question), so I am using 2 substitute calls here, where first one is removing starting `./` with NULL and 2nd substitute call is removing everything from `/` to till last of line with NULL and then printing the line which will give `M1` part.

```
echo "$i" | awk '{sub(/^\.\//,"");sub(/\/.*/,"")} 1'
```

Comment: Like the use of `match()` and `sub()`.

Comment: The one to get M1 prompts CustomersList instead (don't know why). The one to get FCT works as long as it is Boston and not Falls - how could this be fixed?

Comment: @Miguel, when I tested my code with `i=./M1/CustomersList/HTP/Boston/FCT/output_GetCaseList_abs.txt` variable posted in question it worked fine for me, is your variable exactly same as shown? For `FCT` you mentioned `/F` will be constant so I have written regex as per that only.

Comment: there was an error in the variable due to me being in a different folder. Thanks! It works now!

Answer (score 2):

Bash allows you to split a string into an array.

```sh
# starting value
str=./M1/CustomersList/HTP/Boston/FCT/output_GetCaseList_abs.txt

# split string on / delimiter into the split array
IFS=/ read -ra split <<<"$str"

# get M1 and FCT elements at their respective indexes
M1=${split[1]}
FCT=${split[5]}

# dump M1 and FCT variables for demo purpose
declare -p M1 FCT
```

Comment: Nicely done. Herestring and all.

Answer (score 2):

Another option with `awk` is `split()` to split the path components into an array. The array `a[]` is filled by the command below and the 2nd and 6th elements (`"M1"`, and `"FCT"`)

```sh
awk '{split($1,a,"/"); print a[2]", "a[6]}'
```

**Example Use/Output**

```sh
$ i=./M1/CustomersList/HTP/Boston/FCT/output_GetCaseList_abs.txt; echo "$i" | 
awk '{split($1,a,"/"); print a[2]", "a[6]}'
M1, FCT
```

Answer (score 2):

If the positions of the strings are always after the same number of forward slashes, you can print the 2nd and the 6th field, setting the field separator to `/`

```
echo "$i" | awk -F"/" '{print $2, $6}'
```

Output

```
M1 FCT
```

---

You might also use `gnu awk` and a pattern with 2 capture groups matching the following `Cus` for the first match, and starting with `F` for the second match.

The negated character class `[^\/]*` matches 0 or more characters except a `/`

```
echo "$i" | awk 'match($0, /[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\/Cus.*\/(F[^\/]*)/, a) {print a[1], a[2]}'
```

Answer (score 2):

You have your awk answers, but I felt like contributing a bash idea just for fun.

```sh
[[ "$i" =~ ^\./([[:alnum:]]+)(/[[:alnum:]]+){3}/([[:alnum:]]+)/.* ]] \
    && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
```

`BASH_REMATCH` array matches the capture groups in the test case. Index `0` is the complete string.

---

A slightly shorter version yielding the same output:

```sh
[[ "$i" =~ ^\./(.+)(/.+){4}/.* ]] \
    && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ${BASH_REMATCH[2]:1}"
```